# Is there any Git GUI which supports .mailmap?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, smartgit

I'd like to find a GUI for git which supports .mailmap (the --use-mailmap flag of git log).  Ideally this would be in SourceTree or SmartGit but I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Git Extensions](https://gitextensions.github.io/) honors `.mailmap`.

See [relevant documentation](http://git-extensions-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/maintenance.html) for details. Scroll down to `Fix user names`.

Comment: Git Extensions' browser works flawlessly.  I didn't see anything specific to Git Extensions about enabling it but it worked right off the bat: possibly because I already had log.mailmap=true.

Comment: Glad it worked. I never had to change any config to make it work.